# Can't send requests to google

Tags: node.js, search, google-api, request, google-search

I am sending a lot of requests per second to google from my web application (my server works on nodeJS). After several attempts google blocks my requests and respond with error. Is there any API for sending a lot of requests ?

Comment: How many is "a lot"?

Comment: can you specify what kind of requests and how many?

Answer (score 0):

You can try JSON/Atom Custom Search API. It's free verson gives you opportunity of 100 query a day.You must create Key for your API and put it in link below`
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures

here is the introduction of API [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction#identify_your_application_to_google_with_api_key)